# Cannot get CustomerID data into table while all the other data along with CustomerID are in console

Tags: angular, frontend

I am new to angular. Recently I tried using Dot net core web Api and angular for front end. I am getting all the data from the api in console. While displaying them in a table the customerID field is blank. That prevents me from Deleting/Editing particular entry because the customerID is undefined.

HTML for TableComponent

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Customer Table</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="display: flex; justify-content: right;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;Create New Customer</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Shipping Address</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customerService.customers; index as i">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <b>{{i + 1}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{customer.customerId}}
            </td>
            <td (click)="displayCustomer(customer)">
                {{customer.firstName}} {{customer.lastName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{customer.shippingAddress}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{customer.contactNo}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{customer.email}}
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i class="fas fa-edit text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" (click)="populateCustomer(customer)"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="removeCustomer(customer.customerId)"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Model Class

```
export class Customer {
    customerId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    shippingAddress: string;
    contactNo: string;
    email: string;
}
```

C# model class

```
namespace WebAPIwithAngular.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max 25 characters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Max 25 characters")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Shipping Address")]
        public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone No.")]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-z0-9_.]+)@([a-z]+).([a-z]+)?(.[a-z]+)")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Getting Values in Console

```
Array(10)
0: {customerID: 3, firstName: 'Buddhika', lastName: 'Gurung', shippingAddress: 'Samakushi', contactNo: '9847475859', …}
1: {customerID: 4, firstName: 'Ravindra', lastName: 'Pandey', shippingAddress: 'Jhor', contactNo: '9384758694', …}
2: {customerID: 5, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', shippingAddress: 'Minnesota', contactNo: '9849384958', …}
3: {customerID: 6, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', shippingAddress: 'New York', contactNo: '9586458756', …}
4: {customerID: 7, firstName: 'Hari', lastName: 'Bahadur', shippingAddress: 'Jorpati', contactNo: '9847575847', …}
5: {customerID: 8, firstName: 'Madan', lastName: 'Bahadur', shippingAddress: 'Chabahil', contactNo: '9837570847', …}
6: {customerID: 9, firstName: 'Tony', lastName: 'Stark', shippingAddress: 'New York', contactNo: '9485736253', …}
7: {customerID: 13, firstName: 'Prabin', lastName: 'Khati ', shippingAddress: 'Kathmandu', contactNo: '9847475859', …}
8: {customerID: 15, firstName: 'hello', lastName: 'world', shippingAddress: 'Kathmandu', contactNo: '9849384958', …}
9: {customerID: 16, firstName: 'Firstname', lastName: 'Lastname', shippingAddress: 'Desktop', contactNo: '9384758694', …}
length: 10
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Rendered HTML page for the TableComponent with ID fields blank
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5vMi.png)

this is my first time asking question here so I don't know how to post images like I used to see them.

Comment: Can you share the HTML you use in your Angular component?

Comment: Welcome. You should not post code or anything else that is represented in textual form. Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions on posting code...and I have shared HTML Angular component as well

Answer (score 1):

you have costomerId in your typescript class but recieve customerID form server.